# Jquery Repeater + Selectpicker display error

Tags: laravel-blade, bootstrap-selectpicker, jquery.repeater

Currently I am using 2 libraries which are:

```
Selectpicker:
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js') }}"></script> 
Jquery Repeater:
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/jquery-repeater/repeater.min.js') }}"></script>
```

When I click the button with attribute 'data-repeater-create' my select box shows 2 times

The first select tag has a value inside and the second select tag has nothing

So is there a way when clicking on the 'data-repeater-create' attribute that only shows 1 time the select tag with the value inside?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8Wh.png)

My HTML in Blade:

```
<div class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="kpiKeys">
        <div class="row" data-repeater-item>
            <div class="col-8 col-md-8 mb-3">
                <select class='selectpicker repeater-select' required style="font-size:var(--fz-12)" title="My key"
                    data-live-search="true" name="id" data-size="4" data-actions-box="true"
                    data-live-search-placeholder="Search...">
                    @foreach ($kpiKeys as $kpiKey)
                        <option value="{{ $kpiKey->id }}">
                            {{ $kpiKey->name }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3 mb-3">
                <input type="number" min="0" required class="form-control" placeholder="Value"
                    name="quantity" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 col-md-1 mb-3 d-flex align-items-center">
                <img data-repeater-delete role="button" src="{{ asset('/assets/img/trash.svg') }}" width="20px"
                    height="20px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
            <div role="button" class="fs-4 text-danger" data-repeater-create><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to show 1 selection per click